# how to handle multiple confirmation events in dialogflow fulfillment using actions-on-google library

Tags: events, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

In my agent, I have three intents which requires confirmation.

conversation flow

```
user: my number is 000-000-0000
bot: is number 000-000-0000 correct, please confirm?
user: yes
bot: got your number, is your ${location.address} is correct, please confirm?
user: yes
bot: great got your number and address.
```

this is my code

```
app.intent('CustomerNumberIntent', (conv, parameters) => {
        if (conv.user.storage.serviceType === 'Take Away') {
        conv.ask(new Confirmation(`Is ${customerNumber} is correct number?`));
        } else {
        conv.close(`There might be some issue please try again!`);
        }
});

app.intent('CustomerNumberConfirmationIntent', (conv, parameters, confirmationGranted) => {
    if (confirmationGranted){
      conv.contexts.set(AppContextsDefaultAddConfirm.AWAITING_DEFAULT_ADDRESS_CONFIRMATION, 1);
      conv.ask(new Confirmation(`You want delivery at ${defaultAddress}. Is that right?`));
    } else {
      conv.ask(`Tell me the correct contact number?`);
    }
});

app.intent('CustomerAddressConfirmationIntent', (conv, parameters, confirmationGranted) => {
  const contexDefaultAddConfirm = conv.contexts.get(AppContextsDefaultAddConfirm.AWAITING_DEFAULT_ADDRESS_CONFIRMATION);
  const contexUserAddConfirm = conv.contexts.get(AppContextsUserAddConfirm.AWAITING_USER_ADDRESS_CONFIRMATION);
    if (confirmationGranted){
      conv.close(`Great! I got your number and address.`);
    } else {
      conv.ask(`Where to deliver your order?`);
    }
});

app.intent('CustomerAddressIntent', (conv, parameters) => {
  conv.contexts.set(AppContextsUserAddressConfirmation.AWAITING_USER_ADDRESS_CONFIRMATION, 1);
  const deliveryAddress = parameters.deliveryAddress;
    if (conv.user.storage.serviceType === 'Home Delivery'){
        conv.ask(new Confirmation(`Your delivery address is ${deliveryAddress}, please confirm?`));
    } else {
        conv.close(`There might be some issue please try again!`);
    }
});
```

need help in having that conversation flow, don't know how to handle these two confirmations.

I also added contexts but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you update your question with screen shots of the Dialogflow Intent editing screens that you think should be triggered in each case and what isn't working with your code as it exists now? (Are there errors? What is happening instead of what you expect? etc)

Comment: thanks, @Prisoner for your reply, but the issue is resolved I just added the conditions o manage the states.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem! You may want to add an answer that illustrates what you were doing wrong and the solution, so others who may find this question can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by removing the contexts and adding the conditions.

my updated code

```
app.intent('CustomerNumberIntent', (conv, parameters) => {
        if (conv.user.storage.serviceType === 'Take Away') {
        conv.ask(new Confirmation(`Is ${customerNumber} is correct number?`));
        } else {
        conv.close(`There might be some issue please try again!`);
        }
});

app.intent('CustomerNumberConfirmationIntent', (conv, parameters, confirmationGranted) => {
    if (confirmationGranted && !conv.user.storage.customerNumber){
      conv.data.customerNumber = customerNumber;
      conv.user.storage.customerNumber = conv.data.customerNumber;
      conv.ask(new Confirmation(`Your delivery address is ${conv.user.storage.address}. Is that right?`));

    } else if (confirmationGranted && conv.user.storage.customerNumber){
      conv.ask(`Great! your order is placed`);

    } else if (!confirmationGranted && !conv.user.storage.customerNumber){
      conv.ask(`Please tell me the correct number?`);

    } else if (!confirmationGranted && conv.user.storage.customerNumber){
      conv.ask(`Please tell me where to deliver your order?`); 
    }
});

app.intent('CustomerAddressIntent', (conv, parameters) => {
    if (conv.user.storage.serviceType === 'Take Away'){
        conv.ask(new Confirmation(`Your delivery address is ${deliveryAddress}, please confirm?`));
    } else {
        conv.close(`There might be some issue please try again!`);
    }
});
```